# Another word for 'multi' pathed?

Tags: word-choice

eg you can transition into

new social contexts

new worlds

new lifestyles

therefore we can say that the process of transition has many paths..

However, is there a better phrase / word etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition process

- **can take many paths**
- **may have various destinations**
- **can take many forms**

Or. . . say the paths of transition are

- **many [and varied]**
- **numerous**
- **mutifarious**

Comment: multifarious: I like

Answer (score 0):

River channels are often **[braided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_river)**.